# How to remove data from firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble removing data from my database on Firebase. I am able to remove  data but when I remove the data its removing all my users? I only wanted it to remove the user represented in the user ID.

My JS

```
function removeUser(userID){ 

var userRef = firebase.database().ref('users/');

// Returned no user found
//var userRef = firebase.database().ref('users/').child('userID');

// Returned reference child error
//var userRef = firebase.database().ref('users/').child(userID);


userRef.once('value', function(snapshot) { 
    if (snapshot.val() === null) { 
        alert("no user found"); 
    }else{
        userRef.ref.remove();
    }
});
console.log('Remove Success');
}   

    document.getElementById('removeUserBtn').addEventListener('click', function(){

    removeUser(userID);

});
```

Comment: No. Mine is JavaScript the link you provided is java

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the full path to the child you are trying to remove:

```
var childUserRef = firebase.database().ref(`users/${userId}`)
```

and call the `.remove()` method as in : `childUserRef.remove()`

More details:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference

Comment: When I type is  'var userRef = firebase.database().ref('/users/usr4');' this works but I want it to be that I type in any usr value to remove. I tried 'users/${userID}' I got a reference child error and when I try var userRef = firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userID);' I also get a reference error